# Which search strategy in SQL (postgres) to use in order to find similar strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a table with records in one column which are just different by how they are written.
So how can I find those and save the corresponding id's in a new table?

e.g. I have the following records in a column for cities.

```
Id name
1 berlin
2 ber lin
3 ber-lin
4 Berlin
5 Hamburg
6 New York
7 NewYork
```

So my first assumption would be to remove any special characters including white spaces, then lowercase. And see who matches and then write the id to a new table?

What would be the best and most reliable way to find machtes?

Comment: What you trying to do here? Are you trying to do full text search?

Comment: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/158-Where-is-soundex-and-other-warm-and-fuzzy-string-things.html

Comment: @SleimanJneidi Well, not sure if it's full text. In the example above I just want a result in a new table which looks like this : BERLIN 1,2,3,4  HAMBURG 5 NEWYORK 6,7

Comment: Maybe you could use http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html

Comment: Soundex and stuff like that might be an idea. What about stripping the string? And how to save the found records in a new table with the unified name as mentioned in the comment to SleimanJneidi ?

Comment: The best way depends on the exact and complete definition of the problem. A hand full of examples are probably not doing it justice. What's supposed to be folded, and what not? Are completely random typos possible, too?

Comment: I believe fuzzystrmatch is the approach needed unless the table is very, very large; see my revised answer with code. -http://stackoverflow.com/a/26685804/28604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If removing some characters (' ' and '-' in the example) and lower-casing is enough to identify duplicates:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_folded AS
SELECT lower(translate(name, ' -', '')) AS base_name
     , array_agg(id) AS ids
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/28efe7/1)

[`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is particularly useful to replace (or remove) a list of single characters.
Use [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) to create a new table from the results of a query.

Related:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Answer (score 0):

This could certainly be optimized but it works :

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES ('', 'berlin');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES ('', 'ber lin');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES ('', 'ber-lin');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES ('', 'Berlin');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES ('', 'Hamburg');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES ('', 'New York');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES ('', 'NewYork');

CREATE TABLE tmp_clean_text (id INT(9) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_clean_text (id, name) SELECT id, REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(name), ' ', ''), '-', '') FROM test;

CREATE TABLE results (name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO results (name) SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tmp_clean_text;
UPDATE results SET results.name = CONCAT(results.name, ' ', (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tmp_clean_text.id)
    FROM tmp_clean_text
    WHERE tmp_clean_text.name = results.name
));

DROP TABLE tmp_clean_text;
```

Comment: Elements like `INT(9)` or `GROUP_CONCAT()` are specific to MySQL and won't work in Postgres.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the postgresql tag in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying for low [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance). When I had a similar problem with low-quality, manually entered data, I used a list of "correct" place names (perhaps "New York" in your sample data), and then used a cross join of all the rows of bad data and all of the correct names, computed the edit distance for each pairing, and took the minimum for each pairing as the "match."

PostgreSQL includes the Levenshtein edit distance function in its [fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) library, as others have mentioned.

Edit: here's some code, assuming `cities` contains the data in the post and `normalized_cities` contains `(HAMBURG, BERLIN, NEWYORK)` per the later comment:

```
 select distinct id, name, first_value(normalized_name)
        over (partition by id order by edit_distance)
 from (
 select id, name, normalized_name, 
        levenshtein(upper(name), normalized_name) edit_distance
   from cities cross join normalized_cities
 ) all_pairs

  id |   name   | first_value  
 ----+----------+-------------
   1 | berlin   | BERLIN
   2 | ber lin  | BERLIN
   3 | ber-lin  | BERLIN
   4 | Berlin   | BERLIN
   5 | Hamburg  | HAMBURG
   6 | New York | NEWYORK
   7 | NewYork  | NEWYORK
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a list with normalized cities. Of course you can get one in the web but I need the same logic in order to match last names where this approach would not work

Comment: Well, you can cross join the table with itself @dc10, but then you have to set some maximum edit distance where two entries might be considered "same," and you likely would have to have a human involved to review the choices.

Comment: Human review is barely possible since we talk about more than 1m records

Comment: Hah, more to the point, my method here will create a trillion rows to process for comparison. When I used it, it was to correct only several thousand street addresses. Good luck!

Comment: There were a few dozen that needed manual intervention. With your setup that may be several thousand that need manual intervention. Good luck! I think my general approach here is correct, but the size of the table might require some SQL cleverness. Perhaps skipping all of the rows that match another row exactly and only processing the unique typos?